# Python REST client simpler to use than Requests

Tags: python, rest

I remember seeing a REST API client module for Python that was way easier to use than Requests. Can't find it now. Before I write a wrapper of my own, would like to ask around first.

It was smth like this:

```
>>> r = rest.API("http://example.com/api")
>>> r.foo(arg1=["a","b","c"],arg2=2)
{
  'bar': 'baz'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DRest](https://github.com/datafolklabs/drest) is the closest I currently see:

(From its tutorial)

> ```
> import drest
>
> # Create a generic client api object
> api = drest.API('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/')
>
> # Make calls openly via any HTTP Method, and any path
> # GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/1/
> response = api.make_request('GET', '/users/1/')
>
> # Or attach a resource
> api.add_resource('users')
>
> # Get available resources
> api.resources
> >>> ['users', 'projects', 'etc']
>
> # Get all objects of a resource
> # GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/
> response = api.users.get()
>
> # Get a single resource with primary key '1'
> # GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/1/
> response = api.users.get(1)
>
> # Create a resource data dictionary
> user_data = dict(
>     username='john.doe',
>     password='oober-secure-password',
>     first_name='John',
>     last_name='Doe',
>     )
>
> # POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/
> response = api.users.post(user_data)
>
> (etc)
> ```